# What are these CONNECT messages in my log?

Tags: django, http

I'm playing around with a free AWS EC2 instance and django.

I accidentally left my development server running overnight (on port 8080). This morning, the connection log shows a few messages like this:

```
# Me
[16/Aug/2012 19:16:09] "GET /static/img/banner-1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 68263
[16/Aug/2012 19:16:09] "GET /static/img/footer.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4261
[16/Aug/2012 19:16:09] "GET /static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
# Not me
[17/Aug/2012 01:33:59] "GET http://www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1717
[17/Aug/2012 04:13:29] "GET http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbs=qdr:d&prmd=imvns&filter=0&lr=&as_epq=%KEYWORD% HTTP/1.1" 404 1815
[17/Aug/2012 04:13:30] "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.0" 404 1784
```

What are these messages?

Comment: Looks like your development server is connected to the internet...

Comment: @Jingo But what are those messages?

Comment: As far as the log reveals, someone tried to get the page www.baidu.com and this wasnt found (404). I dont know your network setup and why such a request "lands" on your development server. Sorry that I can only state the obvious :/

Comment: aha, some googling revealed that those CONNECT messages could be attempts to connect to your server as mailing service or via telnet command...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Port 8080 is frequently used for http proxy servers. Some bot that found your development server tried to use it as a normal proxy (the first two `GET` commands), then as a transparent proxy for https (which is initiated by sending `HTTP CONNECT` and also explains why it was connecting to google port 443). It was testing to see if your server was an open proxy because open proxies can be used for all sorts of nefarious purposes.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great explanation. I've restricted the IPs that can connect to just me for now. China is scary.